# Rails 5 partial rendered with AJAX is showing stale data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5

After submitting a form with `remote: true` I am trying to update the data on the page with that from the form.  Currently the partial is being re-rendered but the data is stale.  It takes two form submissions for the data to be updated (it is always stale by one form submission).  Thanks for any ideas you can give.

**edit.js.erb**

```
$('.encounter-edit-form').bind('ajax:success', function() {
   var editedEncounterRow = $('#encounter-index-record-<%= @encounter.id %>');
   $(editedEncounterRow).html("<%= j render 'encounter_index_table_ajax_row', encounter: @encounter");
});
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
    <%= form_with(model: encounter, remote: true, :class => "encounter-edit-form") do |form| %>
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a fix for this - turns out I should have been putting the js code in "update.js.erb" instead of "edit.js.erb" to access the updated data.